# How to calculate permittivity of a fluid

Tags: sensor, capacitor, analog

I am confused about calculating permittivity of a fluid.  Permittivity differs from one fluid to another.

$$\epsilon=\epsilon_r\epsilon_0$$

Since it is an electrical property combined with an electrical capacity, it is possible to measure it indirectly in a capacitive sensor. I have used a capacitive sensor to measure the electric relative permittivity factor of a dielectric medium, which can be expressed as a ratio of capacity \$C_x\$ of a capacitor whose space between and around the electrodes is completely filled with the medium, to capacity \$C_0\$ of the same electrodes in vacuum.

$$\epsilon_r= C_x/C_0$$

I know and measured \$C_0\$ value. I am facing problems with calculating \$C_x\$ of the capacitor whose space between and around the electrodes is completely filled with the medium.

I am using method as described below.

I am applying an A.C signal (125 KHz) to the capacitive sensor which is filled with some fluid; in response I am getting an A.C. signal with some phase difference. I am able to measure the amplitudes of the sensor input and sensor output signals and their phase difference also. I am trying to make an equation that will give \$C_x\$ value from above known values (\$V_g\$ (input), \$V_r\$ (output), \$\phi\$ (phase difference)).

Comment: Besides this site, you might find a number of experts with relevant knowledge on the [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: By definition, \$ C = \frac{\varepsilon \varepsilon_0A}{d} \$ , where \$ \varepsilon_0 \$ is the permittivity of free space, A is the Area of your capacitor, and d is the distance between the plates.  \$\varepsilon\$ is the permittivity of the insulator, or what you're looking for.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I am trying to find the permitivity of the medium or insulator or fluid( $$\epsilon_r). I am using Capacitive sensor to estimate the permitivity of the medium or fluid flowing in that Capacitive sensor.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to compare it with a known capacitor C1 in a bridge. If you will excuse very crude ASCII circuits...

Either of the following combinations would be suitable

```
AC --- C1 --- V1 --- CX --- Gnd
|----- R1 --- V2 --- RX --- Gnd
```

or

```
AC --- RX --- V1 --- CX --- Gnd
|----- R1 --- V2 --- C1 --- Gnd
```

C1 should be about the centre of the expected permittivity range times C0.

In either case, adjust RX until V1=V2 (the output of a differential amplifier calculating V2-V1 is 0) at which point RX/R1 = CX/C1 giving you an easy reading of permittivity.

It will also tell you if the medium is lossy (e.g. if the fluid is conductive to some extent). In that case, there is no zero on V2-V1, but just a minimum, where V2-V1 is 90 degrees out of phase with Vin. The magnitude of the out-of-phase component gives some estimate of the loss.

Comment: Thanks for your repla, I didn't get your concept fully. If don't mine can you give some more brief description. Cx(capacity of medium), C1 what is it? and Rx is resistance of medium?

Comment: C1 is a capacitor whose value you know. R1 is a resistor whose value you know. Rx is a resistor you can adjust to find the "balance point" (V1=V2), such as a programmable resistor. I did call the basic idea a "bridge" assuming you would already know the term, sorry about that. Search for "Wheatstone Bridge" and then "AC bridge" and you'll find all you need to know about a very powerful measurement technique.

Answer (score 0):

With just a capacitor, you will actually not see a phase difference.  The reason you do see a phase difference is because of the load impedance of your measuring device.  If this is known, you can use that in your calculation.  If it is large but unknown, choose a smaller load resistor to give a known load impedance.

The voltage across the load resistor will be the instantaneous current through that (and by extension through the capacitor), whose phase you can compare to the phase of the input voltage.

Alternatively, you may be able to measure the peak amplitude across the load resistor, and analyze the circuit as an impedance voltage divider (just like a resistive one, only with complex numbers) with the impedance of the capacitor forming the top and the impedance of the resistive load forming the bottom.

If your expected capacitance is in the range of ordinary components - a few pF to a few hundred uF there are fairly simple capacitance meters available which could simplify the task.  These include formal instrument, and surprisingly good microcontroller-based kits which measure charging time constants rather than using AC excitation.

Comment: yes as you said I am seeing phase difference because of resistance. I know that resistance (1000 ohms) and i am able to measure phase difference between input and across resister. I am able to measure amplitudes at input of sensor and at the load resister. Then i am confusing to to get equation for Cx. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't put much effort into it, but I've never had that much success with a capacitive bridge. These days, I just build the capacitive sensor into a 555-timer circuit, and then I have a pulse width proportional to capacitance, and its easier to interface to a computer or microcontroller this way.   If I have a clock available, a monostable circuit is the way to go, or else a bistable circuit is good, but the frequency will change as well at the pulse width.  Below is a monostable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your circuit is configured as a low pass filter and looks like this:
[image]

the transfer function of a LP filter is:

- \$H(\omega) = \frac{1}{1+2\pi RfC_{0}j} \$

the phase of the transfer function

- \$Arg(H(\omega)) = Atan(-{2\pi RfC_{0}}) = \theta_{0}\$ measured in Radians
- therefore \$ Tan(\theta_{0}) = -{2\pi RfC_{0}}\$
- \$\frac{Tan(\theta_{x})}{Tan(\theta_{0})} = \frac{C_{x}}{C_{0}}  \$

Where \$\theta_{x}\$ is the phase relative to the input for the dielectric present, \$\theta_{0}\$ is the phase relative to the input without any dielectric (other than air) with corresponding \$C_{x}\$ & \$C_{0}\$.

I'd recommend using the zero crossing to get more accurate measurement of time rather than the peaks.